# Cannot write to .service file from bash command

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to execute this command `sudo echo "banana" >> /etc/systemd/system/wallChange.service`, but I am getting this error message: `bash: /etc/systemd/system/wallChange.service: Permission denied`. Previously, I managed to run `sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/wallChange.service` successfully, therefore creating the **/etc/systemd/system/wallChange.service** file. How can I bypass this situation? I need to add the content of the **/etc/systemd/system/wallChange.service** file using a bash command, as these commands are going to be run from a node.js program, which doesn't allow me to open an editor through bash, such as doing something like `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/wallChange.service`

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleagues answered me this question, thanks, Jake :)

The problem was that I was running `echo` command with su privileges, but I had to actually run bash in su mode. Therefore, the command which solved the problem is: `sudo bash -c "echo ‘banana’ >> /etc/systemd/system/wallChange.service”`